# Prove convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x\sin(x)}{x^{4}-\pi^{4}}dx$

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Given $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x\sin(x)}{x^{4}-\pi^{4}}dx$, prove that the integral converges. I thought about splitting the integral and using the direct comparison test, but I'm not sure what function to use.

Comment: The integrand has singularities at $x=\pm \pi$.  You need to check what happens in those neighborhoods.  Outside these neighborhoods the integrand is bounded and is bounded by $\frac {1}{x^3}$ for large $|x|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\left\lvert\dfrac{x\sin x}{x^4-\pi^4}\right\rvert\leqslant\dfrac x{x^4-\pi^2}<\dfrac1{x^3}$ when $x\geqslant 4$, the integral $\displaystyle\int_4^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^3}$ converges, then the integral $\displaystyle\int_4^\infty\frac{x\sin x}{x^4-\pi^4}\,\mathrm dx$ converges. By almost the same argument, the integral $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{-4}\frac{x\sin x}{x^4-\pi^4}\,\mathrm dx$ converges too.

Comment: Given that $x = \pi$ and $x = -\pi$ are removable discontinuities, $\int_{-4}^{4} f(x) dx$ is a regular Riemann integral. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$x \not =π$;

0) $f(x):=\dfrac{x\sin x}{x^4-π^4}$;

$f(-x)=f(x)$, even;

Consider $2\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\infty}}f(x)dx$;

$f(x):=\dfrac{-x\sin (x-π)}{(x-π)(x+π)(x^2+π^2)}$;

Define:

$f(π):=\dfrac{-π}{(2π)(2π^2)}$.

$f$ is continuos on $[0,\infty)$.

Split:

1) $\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{2π}}f(x)dx +\int_{2π}^{\infty}f(x)dx;$

For $x \ge 2π$:

$|\dfrac{-x\sin (x-π)}{(x-π)(x+π)(x^2+π^2)}|\le$

$\dfrac{x \cdot 1}{πx(x^2)}=\dfrac{1}{πx^2}$;

$\displaystyle{\int_{2π}^{\infty}}\dfrac{1}{πx^2}dx$ converges.

Used: $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\sin y}{y}=1$, and

$|\sin y| \le 1.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

It's simpler with some *asymptotic analysis*:

- Near $\infty$, we have
  $$\frac{x\sin x}{x^4-\pi^4}=O\Bigl(\frac1{x^3}\Bigr),$$
  and the latter has a convergent integral on $\mathbf R$, so the given integral is absolutely convergent.
- Near $\pi$
  $$\frac{x\sin x}{x^4-\pi^4}=-\frac{x\sin(x-\pi)}{(x-\pi)(x+\pi)(x^2+\pi^2)}\sim_\pi-\frac{x}{(x+\pi)(x^2+\pi^2)},$$
  and the latter function is defined in a small neighbourhood of $\pi$ (it is equivalent to $-\frac1{4\pi^2}$.

Similarly, near $-\pi$, we have the equivalence
$$\frac{x\sin x}{x^4-\pi^4}\sim_{-\pi}-\frac{x}{(x-\pi)(x^2+\pi^2)}\sim -\frac1{4\pi^2}.$$

Comment: But you did not include the check that your integrand is bounded near $\pi$ and $-\pi$.

Comment: @GEdgar: Right, I  had forgotten to consider these cases. I've fixed it.